# How can the "Supercharge" feature be activated with a pen?

Tags: controllers, sky-force-reloaded

Recently I've acquired the "Main Weapon Supercharge" card. Its activated by holding two fingers on the screen and releasing them. I couldn't find a way to activate it when I play the game with the pen of my Note phone. Does anyone know of a way to do it with a pen?

Comment: have you tried... using a pen and *one* finger?